# erroring out when executing rawquery in sqlite

Tags: android

i am trying to execute rawquery in sqlite in android but its erroring out .

My SQL code is :

```
String sql = "select vaccine_name,vaccine_duration from table_vaccinelists where vaccine_type=";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[10];
    selectionArgs[0] = "'C'";
    Cursor cur = database.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```

Error :

Its giving "Null pointer exception" .i am new to android and i feel there is something wrong the way i have written the where clause in the query .

Comment: what kind of error? what does the logcat say?

Comment: Whats d error? post error log here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something wrong with your query: `selectionArgs` are there to replace question marks in your query.

```
String sql = "select vaccine_name,vaccine_duration from table_vaccinelists where vaccine_type=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"C"};
Cursor cur = database.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
```

However, it shouldn't cause NPE, so something else might be wrong. I think your `database` variable is `null`, check the way you initialise it.